# Authentication Using Passport.js Serving Stating Content Through Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, passport.js

for a project that im currently working on, i decided not to use node's http server, and for a few days i have been trying to figure out how to combine a socket.io-passport app with nginx.To my understanding im forced to use express (for session handling).Its very weird that all the examples i have found on the net, always using node's server for serving static content and noone has made an actual working example with Nginx instead.Let me describe my problem.

Consider the following code

```
app.get('/home', function(reg, res){
    //check user session value, is logged in 
    if(req.user)
        res.render('dash',{
            username: req.user['member_id']//req.user array contains serializeUser data
        });
    else
        res.render('index');

});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){

    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/home');
});

//login form submit as post

app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/home'
    })
    );

app.get('/signup',routes.signup);
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

How do i instruct JavaScript in my js file, to serve static files without routes?

Answer (score 0):

In expressjs you can use static middleware to serve static content from specific folder. You do not need to specify route for that.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

you can access static files in public folder localhost:portnumber/staticfile.js

You may want to prefix static files, you can use this:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

you can access with localhost:portnumber/static/staticfile.js

If you want nginx to serve static files you can simply create new vhost in nginx to serve static files through nginx aswell. 
Generally nginx is used as reverse proxy to proxy all request on port 80 to node.js app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i was referring to a different thing, all the static files will be served by Nginx, this is the purpose of my question.In other words, how i will tell to my application that i will be serving files in different server (Nginx in my case) and not by that native http nodejs server.
Perhaps by using location.href=/signup , location.href=/login etc ?

Comment: you can serve your static files from anywhere, you will need to create vhost in nginx that will point to the static files directory as document root, may be call it static.yoursite.com and in your app refer your static files with static.youtsite.com/staticFile

Comment: @Yalamber I couldn't get any answers to a similar question (different stack wise). Can you please help me with the same?